# Android Update the file content of created file on Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I have done Google drive integration and in integration i have created a file and write some text on the file and save it into the Login user's drive it is running fine but i want to to update the contents of the file i have created a save to drive, i have done allot of research but did not able to find the demo or any code, please any one guide me, i will post my code where i am creating file and saving to my drive

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Button b ,editfile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createfile);
        editfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editfile);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                // create new contents resource
                /**
                 * A code to illustrate how to create a new FILE in the Drive.
                 */
                Drive.DriveApi.newContents(getGoogleApiClient())
                        .setResultCallback(contentsCallback);

            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

     /**
     * Called when activity gets visible. A connection to Drive services need to
     * be initiated as soon as the activity is visible. Registers
     * {@code ConnectionCallbacks} and {@code OnConnectionFailedListener} on the
     * activities itself.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    //.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, 1);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
            }
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
            final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
        return mGoogleApiClient;
    }





    /**
     * A code to illustrate how to create a new FILE with some text on the file in the Google Drive.
     */
    final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error while trying to create new file contents" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            Contents driveContents = result.getContents();
            // write content to DriveContents
            OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            try {
                writer.write(information_data());
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOExceptions=", e.toString());
            }

            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("testFile.txt")
                    .setMimeType("text/plain")
                    .setStarred(true)
                    .build();
            // create a file on root folder
            Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                    .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getContents())
                    .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
        }
    };

    final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error while trying to create the file" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return;
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Created a file: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("result.getDriveFile().getDriveId=", ""+result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
            Log.e("result.getStatus()=", ""+result.getStatus().toString());

            //Opening the file contents Reading files
            driveOpnefileContents(result.getDriveFile());

        }
    };

    public  void driveOpnefileContents(DriveFile driveFile) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("driveOpnefileContents=", "driveOpnefileContents");
        driveFile.openContents(getGoogleApiClient(), DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, new DownloadProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long bytesExpected) {
                 // Update progress dialog with the latest progress.
                Log.e("onProgress=", "onProgress");
                int progress = (int)(bytesDownloaded*100/bytesExpected);
                Log.e("progress", String.format("Loading progress: %d percent=", progress));
            }
        })
        .setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);

    }

    ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsOpenedCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // display an error saying file can't be opened
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"display an error saying file can't be opened" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            // DriveContents object contains pointers
            // to the actual byte stream
            try {
                Contents driveContents = result.getContents();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(driveContents.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                String contentsAsString = builder.toString();
                Log.e("Reading File Contents As String=", ""+contentsAsString);
                driveContents.close();
                /*try {
                    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = driveContents.getParcelFileDescriptor();
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                    // Read to the end of the file.
                    fileInputStream.read(new byte[fileInputStream.available()]);

                    // Append to the file.
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
                    writer.write("editing the contents of the saved file");
                    writer.close();

                    driveContents.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("IOExceptionAppend to the file.=", e.toString());
                    //java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
                }*/
                Log.e("Append to the file.=", "Append to the file.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("IOExceptionAppend to the file2.=", e.toString());
            }

        }
    };

    public String information_data(){
        String result = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jArrayFacebookData = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject jObjectType = new JSONObject();
            // put elements into the object as a key-value pair
            jObjectType.put("info", "facebook_login");
            jArrayFacebookData.put("Result", jObjectType);
            // 2nd array for user information
            JSONObject jObjectData = new JSONObject();
            // Create Json Object using Facebook Data
            jObjectData.put("facebook_user_id", "facebook_user_id");
            jObjectData.put("first_name", "achin");
            jObjectData.put("last_name", "verma");
            jObjectData.put("email", "xvz");
            jObjectData.put("username", "achin");
            jObjectData.put("birthday", "28 april 90");
            jObjectData.put("gender", "male");
            jObjectData.put("location", "mohali");
            jObjectData.put("display_photo", "link");
            jArrayFacebookData.put("data", jObjectData);
            //Log.e("jArrayFacebookData=", ""+jArrayFacebookData);
            result = ""+jArrayFacebookData;
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet 'update' that does what you need (I think). It is using the 'await' call version that has to run off the UI thread or you may turn it into a callback version. You actually need only the portion that starts with

> dFile.open(mGAC, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null)

(after turning DriveId into DriveFile) and make sure you call 'commit' on it

```
  /**
   * update file in GOODrive
   * @param dId   file  id
   * @param titl  new file name (optional)
   * @param mime  new file mime type (optional, null or MIME_FLDR indicates folder)
   * @param buf   new file contents (optional)
   * @return       success status
   */
  static boolean update(DriveId dId, String titl, String mime, String desc, byte[] buf){
    if (dId == null || !isConnected())  return false;   //------------>>>

    Boolean bOK = false;
    Builder mdBd = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder();
    if (titl != null) mdBd.setTitle(titl);
    if (mime != null) mdBd.setMimeType(mime);
    if (desc != null) mdBd.setDescription(desc);
    MetadataChangeSet meta = mdBd.build();

    if (mime == null || UT.MIME_FLDR.equals(mime)) {
      DriveFolder dFldr = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGAC, dId);
      MetadataResult r1 = dFldr.updateMetadata(mGAC, meta).await();
      bOK = (r1 != null) && r1.getStatus().isSuccess();

    } else {
      DriveFile dFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGAC, dId);
      MetadataResult r1 = dFile.updateMetadata(mGAC, meta).await();
      if ((r1 != null) && r1.getStatus().isSuccess() && buf != null) {
        DriveContentsResult r2 = dFile.open(mGAC, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).await();
        if (r2.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
          Status r3 = bytes2Cont(r2.getDriveContents(), buf).commit(mGAC, meta).await();
          bOK = (r3 != null && r3.isSuccess());
        }
      }
    }
    return bOK;
  }
```

the metadata do not need to be updated in your case, so you may modify the code or just pass nulls. Your new content has to be delivered as a byte buffer (String turned to bytes, jpeg data buffer, ...).

The context of this method [can be found here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/GooDrive.java#L211) .  Good Luck

Comment: thanks i will use your code, but before if you look at my contentsOpenedCallback in this i have used ParcelFileDescriptor  to update contents but it is in commented form but when i run the code i got
java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to analyze the code, but in general, you get content  as a stream Stream can be turned to byte array, string. String can be appended, turned into byte array again and written back. Follow 'cont2bytes(cont)' trail here:  https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/GooDrive.java#L190. See the (S)CRUD implementation covers most of what you need on any data storage system, that's why I put those 4 ( search, create, read, update) methods there. And obviously, 'delete' is missing in GDAA..

Comment: Writes 'byte' buffer to a `content` object (stream).

Answer (score 0):

I know, this answer was late, but google always update's his api, so I desided to add answer.
Here is kotlin code, which working by this time

```
fun updateDriveFile(fileCache: File, googleRecentFileModel: GoogleRecentFileModel): Deferred<Boolean> = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async {
        var result = false
        val drive = DriveId.decodeFromString(googleRecentFileModel.stringDriveId).asDriveFile()
        val openFileTask = driveResourceClient?.openFile(drive, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY)
        openFileTask?.continueWithTask { task ->
            val contents = task.result
            contents!!.outputStream.use {
                val fileBytes = ByteArray(fileCache.length().toInt())
                val fileIS = FileInputStream(fileCache)
                fileIS.read(fileBytes)
                fileIS.close()
                it.write(fileBytes)
                it.flush()
                it.close()
                result = true
            }
            driveResourceClient?.commitContents(contents, null)
        }

        result
    }
```